# Average rounds for the lowest player to get to the highest place in the three square game with 3 players.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I am a math student learning at below-college level, but with some knowledge of some more advanced topics. I have been working on a question about 3 square, because I thought it had looked interesting and could be a good exercise. There are 3 players, arranged from the highest place (#1) to the second highest (#2) to the third-highest (#3). Each round, a random player gets out. 
 The rules of progression are the same as in regular 3 square. Each player below the player that got out will move up, and the player that got out will go back to the last place. My question is, how many rounds does it take on average for the lowest player to get to the highest spot?

My work first was that the average time is limit of (p(1) * 1 + p(2) * 2 ....p(x) * x)/x  as x goes to infinity, where p(n) is the probability of getting to the top spot in n moves. To calculate probability, we can rewrite games like this;
 0 is not moving 
 -1 is moving down (getting out) 
 and 1 is moving up. 
 A game of N turns means that 1) there must be a 1 in the last position (so that we know that the first position has not been reached before) and 2) the sum of the entire sequence should be 2.

Additionally, I broke the cases up by the amount of -1s. In the 0 -1s case, there will be 2 1s and the rest are 0s. Therefore, since there is a 1 in the last place, and that 1 will have a probability 1/3 of happening, the only part left is to put the last 1. If it is in the first position, the 1 will have a probability 2/3 and the remaining 0s will all be 1/3. If it is not in the first position, the 0 in the first position will be a 1/3 chance and the 1 which will come at some point after will have a 2/3 chance.

Therefore, the probability of this scenario is 2/3 * (1/3)^(n-1). What gives me trouble is how to create a general formula taking into account the number of -1s so I can solve the problem for the average length of 3 square. My idea is that the amount of 1s increases by the amount of -1s, so the amount of -1s is, say, k, and so the amount of 1s is k+2, and the amount of 0s is n-(2k+2). Then, we need to permute these -1s, 1s, and 0s in all the possible ways, and then we get the amount of games with the set number of -1s.

Comment: I'd suggest you separate this wall of text, parsing it into the points of the question you are trying to answer, relevant observations, context, and the question.  Put some sort of organization  into the wall  of text.

Comment: Please use line breaks (i.e. `<br>`) and paragraph breaks.

Comment: Thank you very much. If there are any other formatting changes, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the state of the players as a discrete stochastic process. Let us assume that there are players $x, y, z$ and we list them from the lowest-ranking one to the highest-ranking one. Then, we have six possible states:
$$(x, y, z), (x, z, y), (y, x, z), (y, z, x), (z, x, y), (z, y, x).$$
Let us denote the above states with $s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5, s_6$, respectively.
As we randomly choose a player to get out each turn, we can build a transition matrix of the process:
$$
A = \begin{array}{c c} 
& \begin{array}{c c c c c c} s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_ 5 & s_6 \\ \end{array} \\
\begin{array}{c c c c c c} s_1 \\ s_2 \\ s_3 \\ s_4 \\ s_ 5 \\ s_6 \end{array} &
\left[
\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
$$

In the above matrix, the value $A_{i, j}$ indicates the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$ in a single turn.

We may without loss of generality assume that we calculate the expected number of rounds from the state $s_1$ to either of the positions where $x$ gets the highest ranking, i.e. states $s_4$ and $s_6$. This allows us to change the probabilities so that if we reach state $s_4$ or $s_6$, we stay there until the end of the game. Now, our matrix looks like this:
$$
A = \begin{array}{c c} 
& \begin{array}{c c c c c c} s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_4 & s_ 5 & s_6 \\ \end{array} \\
\begin{array}{c c c c c c} s_1 \\ s_2 \\ s_3 \\ s_4 \\ s_ 5 \\ s_6 \end{array} &
\left[
\begin{array}{c c c c c c}
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
$$
It's important to note that this operation does not influence the result of our calculations, as we measure the expected time to $\textit{arrive}$ at the given state.
Finally, we can merge our two absorbing states $s_4$ and $s_6$ into a single absorbing state, let us denote it with $s_a$. We just sum the respective probabilities in rows where applicable:

$$
A = \begin{array}{c c} 
& \begin{array}{c c c c c c} s_1 & s_2 & s_3 & s_ 5 & s_a \\ \end{array} \\
\begin{array}{c c c c c c} s_1 \\ s_2 \\ s_3 \\ s_ 5 \\ s_a \end{array} &
\left[
\begin{array}{c c c c c}
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\end{array}
$$
If you are unfamiliar with stochastic processes, there are two facts that are crucial to the calculation:

- the value of $(A^k)_{i, j}$ is the probability that you end up in state $j$ starting in the state $i$ in exactly $k$ steps,
- the expected number of steps may be calculated using leading minors of the transition matrix, which in this case is the $4\times 4$ leading principal minor, or - equivalently - the transient matrix of the process:
  $$
  M = \left[
  \begin{array}{c c c c}
  \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
  0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
  \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
  0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3}
  \end{array}
  \right]
  $$

Now we just need to calculate the expected number of turns to reach state $s_a$ starting from $s_1$. To obtain the result, we calculate the matrix $(I-M)^{-1}$ and sum the values that appear in its first row, as we start in $s_1$.

$$
(I - M)^{-1} = \left[
\begin{array}{c c c c}
\frac{2}{3} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
0 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
-\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{2}{3}
\end{array}
\right]^{-1} = \frac{3}{8}\left[
\begin{array}{c c c c}
6 & 2 & 4 & 4 \\
2 & 6 & 4 & 4 \\
3 & 1 & 6 & 2 \\
1 & 3 & 6 & 2
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The above matrix gives us the expected number of turns required for the lowest ranking individual to reach the highest ranking spot as:
$$\frac{3}{8} (6+2+4+4) = 6$$

Comment: I can understand what is going on until you compute (I-M)^-1. How does this calculate the expected number of turns?

Comment: @CookedTurtle the presented process is an absorbing Markov chain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain. On Wikipedia you will find that $(I-M)^{-1}_{i, j}$ is the expected number of times you will visit state $j$ starting from $i$ - these values are finite, because eventually you will end up in the absorbing state. Therefore, the expected number of turns until you obtain the highest ranking is the sum of the expected numbers of times you will visit the states $s_1, s_2, s_3, s_5$. The formula comes from an identity that $\sum{M^k}_{k=0}^{\infty}=(I-M)^{-1}$

Comment: @CookedTurtle Maybe I should also note why $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} M^k$ is what we are looking for. Note that $M^k_{i, j}$ is the probability of transitioning from the state $i$ to the state $j$ in exactly $k$ steps. In that sense, the probability of transition is the same as the expected number of visits conditioning on the starting state and the number of steps. That is, if $M^k_{i, j}=p$, that means the expected number of visits of the state $j$ in exactly $k$ steps from $i$ is also equal to $p$. Then we sum over all possible values of $k$ to get total expected numbers of visits.